# AWK returns number instead of string for sub/gsub

Tags: awk

I am parsing the output of a command, example:

```
0. BP-726162639-172.16.2.40-1425055855614:blk_1724943006_651672912 len=39498 Live_repl=3 [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.16.2.168:50010,DS-fbfe96c7-82c7-4be3-b056-5a74b3fa2f4b,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.16.2.170:50010,DS-5459e7a0-2874-4a84-b4a4-e7fc84be391f,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[172.16.2.162:50010,DS-86792af4-6db8-478a-97c7-2b6560f2cc19,DISK]]
```

The first sub works as expected but the subs after that fail:

```
awk '{print "block # : " gsub(/\./,"",$1) $2 " :: " sub(/len=/,"a",$3) " :: " $4}'
```

This prints:

```
block # : 1BP-726162639-172.16.2.40-1425055855614:blk_1724943006_651672912 :: 1 :: Live_repl=3
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Is it not ok to use multiple subs?

After understanding @ken's answer it is obvious that I need to do the substitution at the beginning and just use $1 $2 etc later in the print.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: len=39498 => 39498

Comment: I think i got it. Substitution does not return the new string it returns how many replacement was made. I fooled myself assuming it is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

both `gsub` and `sub` worked in your codes.

The two functions will do substitutions, and return the count, how many substitutions were done. (not the string after replacement).

So the `1` before `BP-...` is from `gsub` and the other `1` between `::` s, is from `sub()`.

Comment: How do I get the string that has the substitution?

Comment: @Istvan E.g. after `sub(/foo/,"bar",$3)` , `$3` has been replaced. `$3` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the answer, simply use the variable again after substituting it:

```sh
echo foo-default | awk '{ sub("-default", "", $1); printf "(%s)", $1 }'
(foo)
```